# Where's the right place to drop the Lombok.jar file when using Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

Intellij has a Lombok plugin, but you also need to install the Lombok JAR itself.   The lombok jar's instructions tell you how to install it on Eclipse and Netbeans, but not Intellij IDEA.

Anybody know this?   Put it in the Java bin directory, the Idea bin directory, the project directory...?

I've tried several locations - no luck yet.

Comment: I've only ever installed the plugin, under what circumstance isn't that enough?

Comment: If you use Maven for build just add lombok as a dependency. You probably don't need this jar otherwise.

Comment: Remember to use `provided` dependency to not have lombok stuff be put into your final jar. Same with gradle. If you are not using maven or gradle - just start.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to put the .jar file anywhere special when installing the Lombok plug-in with File->Settings->Plugins.

When installed **lombok-plugin-{version}.jar** will be added in:
**"C:\Users\user\.IdeaIC14\config\plugins"** folder on windows 7.

And do not forget to restart Intelij after plug-in installation.

Answer (score 0):

For me didn't work simply install the Lombok plug-in and enable annotations processing.

I'm using: *IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 EAP (Community Edition)*.

I need to add `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` to the build process option:
*File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | "Shared build process VM options" field*

Source:

- https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2592#issuecomment-705449860
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250718#focus=Comments-27-4418347.0-0